# E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: linux, debian, dpkg

When i typed:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

i get the following errors:

```
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/librtmp0_2.4+20111222.git4e06e21-1_i386.deb (--unpack):
subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
tar: unrecognized option `--warning=no-timestamp'
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess tar returned error exit status 64
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libssh2-1_1.2.8-2_i386.deb (--unpack):
subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
tar: unrecognized option `--warning=no-timestamp'
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess tar returned error exit status 64
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/krb5-locales_1.10+dfsg~beta1-2_all.deb (--unpack):
subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/libkrb5support0_1.10+dfsg~beta1-2_i386.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libk5crypto3_1.10+dfsg~beta1-2_i386.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libkrb5-3_1.10+dfsg~beta1-2_i386.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libgssapi-krb5-2_1.10+dfsg~beta1-2_i386.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libidn11_1.23-2_i386.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/librtmp0_2.4+20111222.git4e06e21-1_i386.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libssh2-1_1.2.8-2_i386.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/krb5-locales_1.10+dfsg~beta1-2_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Please note that i do not find the .deb files in archives directory !

I tried to update and to upgrade but still get the same issue

Comment: The necessary lines are before the `dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/librtmp0_2.4+20111222.git4e06e21-1_i386.deb (--unpack):` part...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think your question can be answered with the information provided, because we do not know, why the processing failed.  This should have been printed on the screen while processing the packages.

In case the errors are due to non-existing or corrupted archives, you can try to clear the archives with `aptitude clean`or `apt-get clean`.

edit:
with the additional info, the problem becomes much clearer.  Obviously there is something wrong between dpkg-deb (a program, which is part of the debian package management used by apt-get) and tar (which is packing/unpacking files from/into single archives).

Now the dpkg-deb is calling tar with an unsopported option, so somehow there is a version mismatch between those programs.

Possible solutions for the problem can be found by searching for the error message, eg.

http://georgik.sinusgear.com/2011/10/06/debian-dpkg-problem-tar-exists-on-unknown-argument-warningno-timestamp/

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21634/tar-unrecognized-option-warning-during-apt-get-install

Comment: I already tried apt-get clean but still get the same issue. Please note that i put more details in my description

Comment: The additional info helped, please see the links above.

Comment: I got the same error, your solution worked. Thanks :) +1

Answer (score -1):

```
apt-get clean
apt-get autoclean
rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/lists
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
apt-get -fy update 
apt-get install -fy linux-firmware < /dev/console > /dev/console & sleep 180
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, could you explain *why* it will fix the problem asked?

Answer (score -1):

Don't worry use this command:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/install-info.postinst /var/lib/dpkg/info/install-info.postinst.bad
```